# SQL: Group by date and summing values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, db2

I have a JDBC database (DB2 specifically but am looking for something DB agnostic, at a minimum DB2 and Oracle) that has a table that, every 10 minutes, gets records inserted with statistics about APIs that are run by the application in question. It looks something like:

```
StatKey, StartDate, EndDate, APIName, StatName, StatValue
201505071498224437562706    2015-05-07 14:12:44.0   2015-05-07 14:22:44.0   API5    Invocations 34
201505071498161437466684    2015-05-07 14:06:14.0   2015-05-07 14:16:14.0   API4    Invocations 79
201505071498060937466556    2015-05-07 13:56:08.0   2015-05-07 14:06:08.0   API4    Average 26,264.37
201505071497263437627286    2015-05-07 14:16:33.0   2015-05-07 14:26:34.0   API2    Invocations 24
201505071497262137620812    2015-05-07 14:16:19.0   2015-05-07 14:26:20.0   API2    Invocations 24
201505071497024537466378    2015-05-07 13:52:43.0   2015-05-07 14:02:44.0   API1    Average 6,830,050
201505071497023337466368    2015-05-07 13:52:31.0   2015-05-07 14:02:32.0   API3    Average 31,523
201505071496023337466361    2015-05-07 13:52:31.0   2015-05-07 14:02:32.0   API2    Invocations 1
201505071494263837628892    2015-05-07 14:16:36.0   2015-05-07 14:26:37.0   API5    Invocations 68
201505071493124437466656    2015-05-07 14:02:44.0   2015-05-07 14:12:44.0   API1    Invocations 2
201505071492263037625304    2015-05-07 14:16:29.0   2015-05-07 14:26:30.0   API3    Average 179,223.29
```

Every 10 minutes, any API executed during that time will have an entry similar to the above. However, multiple JVMs will write to the same database so the start and end times are not simply every 10 minutes and there could be more than 6 entries every hour.

What I'm trying to do is create a SQL that will group per hour all invocations of all API for each hour of run time. For example:

```
Date&Hour, API, Invocations
2015-05-07 12:00, API1, 100
2015-05-07 12:00, API2, 150
2015-05-07 13:00, API2, 200
etc...
```

I've tried doing a GROUP BY based on a SUBSTR of the primary key (which is always the timestamp plus some random numbers - but between the hours and minutes are 2 random digits) at the hour mark but I'm not sure how to add all StatName=Invocations per hour.

Could someone please provide some ideas as to how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
select to_char(StarDate,'rrrr-mm-dd HH24:')||'00'  as DateHour,
    APIName as API,
    sum(StatValue) as Invocations
from STATISTICS
where StatName = 'Invocations' 
group by to_char(StarDate,'rrrr-mm-dd HH24:')||'00', APIName
```

There are differents ways to do this..

Good luck!

Comment: Everything given here is a great possible solution but for my needs, this is relatively simple and seems to work the best for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're after is this it?

in essence it looks at YYYYMMDDHH 10 positions as they contain value to group on... and then sums based on invocations only

```
SELECT substr(statKey,1,10) as DH, APIName, Sum(Statvalue) Invocations
FROM TableName
WHERE StatName = 'Invocations'
GROUP BY substr(statKey,1,10), APIName, StatName
```

Example:

```
WITH CTE AS
  (SELECT '201505071498224437562706' AS StatKey,
    '2015-05-07 14:12:44.0'          AS StartDate,
    '2015-05-07 14:22:44.0'          AS EndDate,
    'API5'                           AS APIName,
    'Invocations'                    AS StatName,
    34                               AS statvalue
  FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201505071498161437466684',
    '2015-05-07 14:06:14.0',
    '2015-05-07 14:16:14.0',
    'API4',
    'Invocations',
    79
  FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '201505071498060937466556',
    '2015-05-07 13:56:08.0',
    '2015-05-07 14:06:08.0',
    'API4',
    'Average',
    26264.37
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT substr(statKey,1,10) as DH, APIName, StatName, Sum(Statvalue) 
FROM TableName
WHERE StatName = 'Invocations'
GROUP BY substr(statKey,1,10), APIName, StatName
```

Answer (score 1):

For DB2 at least, why not just

```
select date(startdate) as start_date
       , hour(startdate) as start_hour
       , API
       , sum(statvalue) as Invocations
from mytbl
where statname = 'Invocations' 
group by date(startdate),  hour(startdate), API
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to combine date and hour back into a timestamp if thats what you really want...

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ad6f/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Data AS
          SELECT '201505071498224437562706' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:12:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:22:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API5' AS APIName, 'Invocations' AS StatName, 34 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071498161437466684' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:06:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:16:14', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API4' AS APIName, 'Invocations' AS StatName, 79 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071498060937466556' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 13:56:08', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:06:08', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API4' AS APIName, 'Average' AS StatName, 26264.37 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071497263437627286' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:16:33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:26:34', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API2' AS APIName, 'Invocations' AS StatName, 24 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071497262137620812' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:16:19', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:26:20', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API2' AS APIName, 'Invocations' AS StatName, 24 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071497024537466378' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 13:52:43', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:02:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API1' AS APIName, 'Average' AS StatName, 6830050 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071497023337466368' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 13:52:31', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:02:32', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API3' AS APIName, 'Average' AS StatName, 31523 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071496023337466361' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 13:52:31', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:02:32', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API2' AS APIName, 'Invocations' AS StatName, 1 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071494263837628892' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:16:36', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:26:37', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API5' AS APIName, 'Invocations' AS StatName, 68 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071493124437466656' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:02:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:12:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API1' AS APIName, 'Invocations' AS StatName, 2 AS StatValue FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '201505071492263037625304' AS StatKey, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:16:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS StartDate, TO_DATE( '2015-05-07 14:26:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS EndDate, 'API3' AS APIName, 'Average' AS StatName, 179223.29 AS StatValue FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT   TRUNC( EndDate, 'HH' ) AS "Date&Hour",
         APIName,
         SUM( StatValue ) AS Invocations
FROM     Data
WHERE    StatName = 'Invocations'
GROUP BY TRUNC( EndDate, 'HH' ),
         APIName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ad6f/2/0)**:

```
|             Date&Hour | APINAME | INVOCATIONS |
|-----------------------|---------|-------------|
| May, 07 2015 14:00:00 |    API2 |          49 |
| May, 07 2015 14:00:00 |    API5 |         102 |
| May, 07 2015 14:00:00 |    API1 |           2 |
| May, 07 2015 14:00:00 |    API4 |          79 |
```

Comment: DB2 seems to have the [TRUNC function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000863.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-168) as well so I think this should work on both (but can't test it).

Answer (score 1):

Date functions seem to be rather difficult to implement in a database agnostic fashion.

For a DB agnostic solution I would suggest creating views in the databases that hide the implementation of DB-specific code, and which therefore allows you to use a straightforward select without any syntactic issues.